# How to select specific text from the string in efficient way using SQL

Tags: sql, string, performance, sql-server-2008, processing-efficiency

Below is my query. It is giving me correct output but I need to run it efficiently as it is used for 500k records.

```
 DECLARE @DESC_MESSAGE VARCHAR(5000)
 SET @DESC_MESSAGE = '12345 VENKAT was entered ODC ABCD-3'
 SELECT REPLACE(@DESC_MESSAGE,SUBSTRING(@DESC_MESSAGE,1,CHARINDEX('was',@DESC_MESSAGE,3)-1),'')
```

I just want to retrieve text after 'was' which can change depending on condition.
for ex. text can be like
'112233 XYZ was entered ODC PQRS-3' or 
'223344 HARRY was gone out of ODC AMD-3'

Please suggest efficient way to retrieve such text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be inclined to use `stuff()`:

```
select stuff(col, 1, chardindex('was ', col + 'was ') + 4, '')
```

The `+ 'was +` in the `charindex()` function just guarantees no error if `'was '` is not in the text.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helped in good way. But in some cases it can give unwanted output when text it self is containing 'was' or is ending with 'was'. So I have corrected the query. Please check above answer.

Comment: @Shardul . . . Your answer looks quite reasonable.

Comment: @Shardul . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Actually I was trying to accept both the answers but automatically yours got unaccepted. Is there any way to mark both as correct answers?

Comment: @Shardul . . . No there isn't.  I was curious why you unaccepted it.  As the OP you are free to accept whichever answer you think is best, and that is only one answer.

Answer (score 0):

half milion rows is not so huge..

what i can see in your question is that there is an architecture issue,

why do you need to split a column to make a query?

why don't you keep the colums splitted in origin ?

eventually you could have another column that contains only the text after the "was"

this could be better even if the rows grow a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
select LTRIM(stuff(@DESC_MESSAGE, 1, CHARINDEX(' was', @DESC_MESSAGE + 'was') + 3, ''))
```